# How to capture a configuration error in play! 2.1.5 to avoid showing default error message?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm working with play! 2.1.5 on a project and today, when running the app, a configuration error was shown saying that it could not connect to the database. It turns out that MySQL was not running, hence the error.

But my question is about how to capture this configuration error and show another page instead of the default error page (pictured below).

[image: Configuration Error shown (with **password visible**)]

As you can see, the default page displays the password right there, which is quite a security risk.

I have already override the *onError* method in my *GlobalSettings* extended class, but this error doesn't seem to be captured by that.

Is there any way to capture this error and show an alternative error message?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are running Play in dev mode (ie using `~run` or `run`). This mode should only be used in development because it may show sensitive information (ex: stacktraces with source code, passwords, etc).

If you want to run in production mode, you can use `start` or `~start` instead

```sh
# Using Play >= 2.3.x
$ activator ~start

# Older versions
$ play ~start
```

Also when you run the artifacts from `stage` and `dist` commands your app will start in production mode.

When in production mode, unless you override the error pages using `Global.onError` you will only see a page stating that happened an internal error and an exception ID that can be used by devs to debug that error.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I forgot to test this in production mode. In fact, in production mode, the app doesn't even run when there's a configuration error (so the default error never appears in the browser).